# App getting crash with following crash log when tapping on an alert's button

Tags: ios, uialertview

In our project, while tapping on alert view's button, app getting crash with following crash log.

Sample Code:

```
 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Room has been checked out.  Please contact Front desk." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Crash Log:

```
Date/Time:       2013-10-10 17:51:11.390 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x62694c37
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b8455b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x357abe7c -[UIWindow firstResponder] + 64
2   UIKit                           0x3581966c -[UIWindow _makeKeyWindowIgnoringOldKeyWindow:] + 300
3   UIKit                           0x357be2b0 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 384
4   UIKit                           0x358ff71a -[UIAlertView(Private) resignFirstResponder] + 38
5   UIKit                           0x358ff292 -[UIAlertView(Private) _performPopoutAnimationAnimated:coveredBySpringBoardAlert:] + 434
6   UIKit                           0x358920c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x35892072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
8   UIKit                           0x35892050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
9   UIKit                           0x35891906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
10  UIKit                           0x35891dfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
11  UIKit                           0x357ba5ec -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
12  UIKit                           0x357a77fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
13  UIKit                           0x357a7116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
....
```

Exception in xcode console:

```
2013-10-10 18:34:05.910 MyProject[1423:907] -[OS_dispatch_queue _windowBecameKey]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd8ac10
```

Comment: What is the exception name and description?

Comment: @Wain, Added the exception in question, pls check.

Comment: Check for zombies in profiler. Or maybe you set delegate for alert and this delegate became deallocated.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique, updated the sample code.

Comment: Crash log updated with error name and description. pls check

Answer (score 1):

this usually happens when you've assigned a selector (in this case to an alert) but the method passed in the selector does not exist, check that if you are not using as the target "self" that the method is public or that if you are using as target "self" that the method exists

Comment: thank you @heczaco: your tip saved me some frustration.